# Increment all values in a list

Tags: python

I know we get to return only one time but is it possible to increment all elements of a list at once.

I know I can do this

```
def test(lst, increment):
   newlst = []
   for value in lst:
      newlst.append(value + increment)
   return newlst
print(test([1,2],1))

OutPut = [2, 3]
```

I feel like the above code is little more work 
Is it possible to return all incremented values?

```
def test(lst, increment):
    for value in lst:
       return value + increment

print(test([1,2],1))

OutPut = 2, 3
```

Comment: What is your function’s goal?

Comment: add the increment with each value of list and return those values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension:

```
def incr(lst, i):
    return [x+i for x in lst]
```

Comment: I knew this idea but thank you. this idea works with multiple lists and subtracts value to each other. Also, we can join str with num.